# How can I design a progress bar in SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, game-engine, scenebuilder

Here a simple question I'd like to ask.
I'm making a videogame (with NO graphics) and for that I'm using SceneBuilder. So here is the state of my HP bar :
[HP BAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCCpp.png)

Now I want to reshape it in order to obtain a heartshape :
[HP BAR wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVM6M.jpg)

Thus, anyone know if it's possible to do it using SceneBuilder with the settings?

Thank you everyone, have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way, providing the background of the panel is simple, would be to overlay an `ImageView` over the top of the progress bar. If you use a PNG with a "hole" of transparency, you'd effectively hide the areas of the square that you're not interested in seeing.

[image: heart]

In this example, the black pixels would be the same colour as the background colour (in your case grey) and the white pixels would be fully transparent.

The downside to this is that if the panel changes colour then you'll need to recreate your PNG in the new colour.

Comment: Oh yeah this is pretty smart actually. I'll create a heartshape with a polygon or an ellipse and superimpose it on the bar. Thank you so much !